# Getting YASnippet and viper-mode to work together in emacs

Tags: plugins, emacs, viper-mode

I use viper-mode in emacs, but I want to use YASnippet as well. However, when I enable viper-mode and try using tab-completion through YASnippet, nothing happens. How do I get the two of them to work together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an Emacs without any customizations (`emacs -q`), I got the following to work:

```
(load-file "c:/cygwin/home/Trey/scratch/yasnippet-bundle.el")
M-x viper-mode
(define-key viper-insert-global-user-map (kbd "<tab>") 'yas/expand)
C-x C-f a.cpp
i
main<TAB>
```

Try that, see if it works (as in, if there's something in your `.emacs` that's messing things up).  Also, check to see what Emacs thinks your <kbd>TAB</kbd> key is.  On my windows system, the tab key was bound to <kbd><tab></kbd> and not <kbd>TAB</kbd> - try doing <kbd>M-x describe-key TAB</kbd> and see what the `*Help*` buffer translates it to.  `yasnippet` appears to bind to <kbd>TAB</kbd>, so I needed the extra binding for <kbd><tab></kbd> to get things to work.

For more information about how Emacs handles the <kbd>TAB</kbd>, read the [documentation for function keys](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Function-Keys.html).

Comment: Perfect, that worked to make viper-mode and YASnippet work together. The only thing is that now, when I press `TAB` to actually insert a tab, it just inserts a space. How can I make it insert a tab when it's not invoking YASnippet to do a completion?

Comment: Correction, it's actually inserting a weird character, not even a space. How do I fix this?